# Space group for vector fields with fractional periods in subspaces

Tags: group-theory, crystals

Consider a periodic system of 3-dimensional vector fields, the corresponding Hamiltonian is a 3-by-3 hermitian matrix:
$$
H(\mathbf{r})=\begin{pmatrix}
a(\mathbf{r}) & 0  & d(\mathbf{r})\\
0 & b(\mathbf{r}) & 0\\
d(\mathbf{r})^* & 0 & c(\mathbf{r})
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Suppose the period of the system is $\mathbf{R}$, $H(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})=H(\mathbf{r})$, however, the elements of the hamiltonian may have smaller periods as fractions of $\mathbf{R}$. For example, $a,c,d$ have period $\mathbf{R}$, but $b$ has a smaller period $\mathbf{R}/4$. I find that the fractional period of the "subspace" can induce additional degeneracy, however, it seems that such additional degeneracy cannot be explained by the irreducible representation of the ordinary space group.

Is there a generalized space group theory describing such periodic systems of vector fields with fractional periods of subspaces?

Comment: If you don't find a good answer here in a few days, you may want to ask on [math.se]

Comment: Could you clarify whether your question is about the representation theory of such situations, or about a classification of possible such groups?

Comment: @LukePritchett I'm intrested in both the two aspects you mentioned, i.t. the representation theory of the corresponding little group in the reciprocal space and the classification of such groups. Indeed, I'm looking for a well-established framework for such groups. And I'm glad to see any ideas about either aspect of such groups.